# How can we tell WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to not wait for a response or a postback?

Tags: perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize, mozrepl, www-mechanize-firefox

Hi I am using a loop to `get` various pages.

The code:

```
while($stm->fetch()) {
    $mech->get(**#TheURL**);

            $mech->select( 'this', 'that' );
            $mech->tick( 'this' => undef );
            $mech->tick( 'this' => undef  );
            $mech->tick( 'this' => undef  );
            $mech->tick( 'this' => undef  );
            my $button = $mech->selector('input.button', single => 1);
            $mech->click($csvbutton);
}
```

The code above downloads the file after clicking the button. However it stops after the first iteration.

I have changed the configuration of Firefox to disable the download manager popup.

I received this error once:

```
MozRepl::RemoteObject::Object has no function addProgressListener at `$mech->get(**#TheURL**);`
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I have found that it gets stuck on the first download because WWW::Mechanize::Firefox is waiting for a response or postback which it does not get. A file is just downloaded.

```
$mech->click($csvbutton);
```

This is the place where it stop. If i manually manipulate the page (ie. go back or go to the homepage or a new URL), it will continue on the loop. So it is waiting for a new page load.

How do i tell WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to not wait for a response or new page load?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format of the line should be perfect of the form:

```
$mech->click({selector => ('input.button', single => 1), synchronize => 0});
```

You must use `selector =>` or `xpath =>`

**Signature:**

```
$mech->click({xpath/selector => 'name' ,synchonize => 0})
```

Then the click will not wait for a response for the webserver.

As stated at: [cpan WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Troubleshooting](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Troubleshooting.pod#Clicking_on_a_link_makes_the_Perl_script_wait_forever)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `synchronize` option for the click:

```
$mech->click( $csvbutton, { synchronize => 0 } );
```

Comment: I have tried that now. It still hangs on the first link, waiting for a postback or new pageload. In the documentation it says: `It is necessary to synchronize with the browser whenever a click performs an action that takes longer and fires an event on the browser object.` When my button is clicked the only `event` that fires is the creation and download of an excel `csv`.